# Access- "Join expression not supported"

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have a query in MySQL that returns three columns, a Candidate's ID, the date they were contacted, and by whom. I'm trying to write a query that ONLY returns the most recent time they were contacted, along with their ID and by whom.

```
SELECT e.ID,
    ByWho,
    Date
FROM ContactSummaries e
JOIN(SELECT ID,
        MAX(Date) AS LastContact
    FROM ContactSummaries
    GROUP BY
        ID) lu
  ON (e.ID = lu.ID AND e.Date = lu.LastContact)
```

So, that right there works perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio. When I paste it into Access to make a nice little Report, it complains about an "Incomplete query clause".

Then I tried this:

```
 SELECT
 ID,
 ByWhom,
 Date
 FROM( ContactSummaries AS [e]
 INNER JOIN
 SELECT ID,
 MAX(Date) AS LastContacted,
 ByWhom
 FROM ContactSummaries
 ON 
 ID, 
 MAX(Date) AS LastContacted,
 FROM ContactSummaries
 GROUP BY ID)
 AS [l]
 ON
 [e].ID = [l].ID,
 AND [e].Date = [l].LastContacted;
```

"Join expression not supported". I don't know SQL (or Access especially) well enough to see what I'm doing wrong, it seems to match their examples on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Join by itself in Access. Note also that Date is a reserved word. I think you want

```
SELECT e.ID,
    ByWho,
    [Date]
FROM ContactSummaries e
inner join (SELECT ID,
        MAX([Date]) AS LastContact
    FROM ContactSummaries
    GROUP BY
        ID) lu
  ON (e.ID = lu.ID AND e.Date = lu.LastContact)
```

Comment: `e.[Date] = lu.LastContact`, surely?

Comment: Hmm, interesting- that seems to work. It gives the same results as that first query I posted that worked in SSMS. Thanks!

Comment: the syntax 'inner join' is the accepted way to do Join in Access

Comment: @Mark Bannister the bracketing is not required because the table name or alias is prefixed. This is always the case in Access, AFAIK.